# Trying to backup to s3 from RDS but getting an error message related to kms:GenerateDataKey, even though the assumed role has the permission

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have followed the instructions for backing up an sqlserver db into s3.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

I've created a role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement":
    [
        {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action":
            [
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:region:account-id:key/key-id"
        },
        {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action":
            [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"
        },
        {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action":
            [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

which I've added, and of course added bucket_name, and the correct key ARN. 
 I've also confirmed that this role is used for the Option Group added to the RDS instance.

However, when I run

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database
@source_db_name='dbname',
@s3_arn_to_backup_to='arn:aws:s3:::s3-bucket/name',
@kms_master_key_arn='arn:aws:kms:region:account-id:key/key-id',
@overwrite_S3_backup_file=1,
@type=‘FULL’;
```

However, this results in:

```
Task has been aborted [] User: arn:aws:sts::account-number:assumed-role/rolename/role is not authorized to perform: kms:GenerateDataKey on resource: arn-to-kms
```

**Note, this works without the kms_master_key_arn option in the msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database call.**

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KMS service is a little bit different from other AWS services in that there is no implicit trust between your account and CMK which means that attaching IAM permissions to a user or a role is not enough.

If you want to use IAM to allow KMS operations, you will need to specify this in key policy - you will need to add full permissions to your account.

```
{
  "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root"},
  "Action": "kms:*",
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

Of course, you will need to change `111122223333` with your account number.

If you don't want to establish this trust between your account and CMK then use key policy instead of IAM and specify the role as a principal.

Be sure that you either keep key administrators or the above statement in your key policy. If you remove both of them, you will lock yourself out of the key and the only way to revert it would be to contact AWS support.